# как получить message id чата где telegram bot admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите, как получить message id чата где telegram bot admin.

Comment: Что значит "message id чата". Почему документация по ссылке https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#message не помогает? Хотелось бы увидеть код, который не работает или вызывает вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Написать в этот чат сообщение, перехватить его, распарсить и вытащить id.
если используется pyTelegramBotAPI, то нужен обычный декоратор перехвата. Можно настроить, например, чтоб перехватывались вообще все сообщения:

```
 @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
```

ну а в функции вытаскивайте все id какие нужно:

```
def catch_all(message): 
    print(message.from_user.id)   
    print(message.message_id) 
    print(message.chat.id)
```